# Does receiving visa quickly indicate good standing with UKVI?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

After having had only 1 short term standard visitor visa, we (me, my wife and our son) applied for a 2-year one. Processing time for our center is currently being displayed as follows:

[image]

We **did not** apply for priority processing but according to the date on the visa stickers our applications were approved on the very first day. They received our applications late on Friday and the visa stickers say they were issued on Monday.

Does that mean we do have good standing with them? Or is that just a coincidence that we are in that **4%** group?

For some background, we do have excellent compliance history with every country we have visited, including the UK.

---

*Lately everyday we see new questions about UK Visa refusals but not any that relates to approvals. There are some old questions in our archives asking about criteria for long term visa applications, I am asking this question so it can be helpful for people looking for that information in the future.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does **not** mean that your application was singled out for especially fast processing. Merely that (like most applications) it was straightforward enough to be decided quickly once someone got around to looking at it, and someone did so quickly because you had the luck to apply on one of the days where they didn't have much of a backlog.

(Mathematical queueing theory predicts that every once in a while the backlog *will* drop down to nothing, unless you're so short-staffed that it will keep growing without bounds).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Are most applications really straightforward? Because I keep seeing tons of refusal questions here with all sorts of complications

Comment: @HankyPanky a lot on here seem to get refused for trying to deceive or parking funds. I bet most visit visas are straight forward if you have nothing to hide and fit the criteria.

Comment: @HankyPanky: There's usually nothing to ask about the straightforward ones (except those that are straightforwardly hopeless), so we don't generally hear about them here. But don't let this selection bias inform what you think is _normal_.